# Where can I find a versatile PKI and library leveraging curve25519?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I note that [Things that use Curve25519](http://ianix.com/pub/curve25519-deployment.html) provides a long list of protocols, software, and libraries that leverage curve25519, but I'm wondering if there is any such software that more fully implements a self-contained PKI ecosystem?  For example, implementing the ability to generate a certificate and distribute it - perhaps in some kind of hierarchical chain of trust.

Which of the projects out there might be closest to providing that?  Perhaps it's one from that list, or maybe it's another PKI system that could use curve25519 (and poly1305-AES/Salsa) as its algorithmic foundation.  For my question, I'm looking for versatility (such as being able to distribute keys or update keys in a way that's authenticated), but I don't necessarily need too much complexity.  However, answers can freely be shared which follow slightly different criteria.

Comment: You haven't *really* specified what you consider complete.

Comment: I don't think there's any readily-built PKI-CA solution that already supports Ed25519 / Curve25519 as the IETF hasn't even yet standardized those curves / algorithms and AFAIK there's no RFC for curve25519 certificates and without standards you'll have a hard time finding support.